# Kusto - Help writing KQL Pivot

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In an IoT project we are gathering sensor data in Azure Data Explorer. All sensor data is stored in a "signals" table. To uniqly identify a timeseries for a given sensor, we query like this:

```
Signals
| where TestId == "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3" and SignalName == "Signal1"
```

We want to be able to Pivot all timeseries from a given TestId, from the "signals" Table Rows into Columns.
I have been unable to write a Kusto Query that Achieves this, and I am hoping for some help on this forum.

**AS-IS**

The current signals table schema looks like this:

| Timestamp | TestId | SignalName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal1 | 23400 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal2 | 0.113 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal3 | 77.5 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal1 | 23450 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal2 | 0.114 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal3 | 75.4 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal1 | 22450 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal2 | 0.113 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | Signal3 | 80.05 |

**TO-BE**

I want to be able to Pivot the Table, to the following Schema:

| Timestamp | TestId | Signal1 | Signal2 | Signal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23400 | 0.113 | 77.5 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23450 | 0.114 | 75.4 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 22450 | 0.113 | 80.05 |

I have tried the following query:

```
let testId = "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3";
signals
| where TestId == testId 
| where SignalName == "Signal1" or SignalName == "Signal2" or SignalName == "Signal3"
| order by Timestamp desc
| evaluate pivot(SignalName)
```

But the resulting table, seems to repeat the timestamp - the timestamp is represented multiple times and a default value "0" is inserted in other signal columns:

| Timestamp | TestId | Signal1 | Signal2 | Signal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23400 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0.113 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0 | 77.5 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23450 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0.114 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0 | 75.4 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 22450 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0.113 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 0 | 0 | 80.5 |

I do not need to do any aggregation using the Pivot operator, since all Signals should have a value on the exact same timestamp.

- Can anyone help me writing a KQL query for this?
- Do I need to create a Materialized View in Azure Data Explorer to Achieve this? An update Policy or Function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the aggregation function in the pivot plugin:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, TestId:string, SignalName:string, Value:double)
[
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  23400,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2", 0.113,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  77.5,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  23450,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2",  0.114,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  75.4,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  22450,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2",  0.113,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  80.05
]
| evaluate pivot(SignalName, sum(Value))
```

| Timestamp | TestId | Signal1 | Signal2 | Signal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23400 | 0.113 | 77.5 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23450 | 0.114 | 75.4 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 22450 | 0.113 | 80.05 |

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer. That worked perfectly! I thought that the sum() function would somehow change the Values in the Value column, but it seems it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, TestId:string, SignalName:string, Value:double)
[
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  23400,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2", 0.113,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:30),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  77.5,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  23450,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2",  0.114,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:31),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  75.4,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal1",  22450,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal2",  0.113,
    datetime(2021-01-01 12:00:32),  "cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3", "Signal3",  80.05
]
| project Timestamp, TestId, P = pack(SignalName, Value)
| summarize make_bag(P) by Timestamp, TestId
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_P)
```

| Timestamp | TestId | Signal1 | Signal2 | Signal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:30.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23400 | 0.113 | 77.5 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:31.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 23450 | 0.114 | 75.4 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:32.0000000 | cbb8bff1-ee9d-4ead-bbd6-c9c246d84fd3 | 22450 | 0.113 | 80.05 |

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This also works great. But the Solution offered by @Avnera seems more simple, using the pivot function like so: | evaluate pivot(SignalName, sum(Value))

Comment: Thanks for sharing! this also works for the scenario where the values are strings and aggregate function cannot be used.